# Hibernate ORM p2 site for RCP Application

Tags: hibernate, eclipse-rcp

I want to use hibernate ORM to manage persistence inside an Eclipse RCP application.  To do this, I need to get the bundles into the target.  For other persistence frameworks (EclipseLink), there is a published p2 site.  I've searched Google but only find references to the Hibernate Tools which is not what is needed for a client application.

Does anyone know if a p2 update site exists or how to get Hibernate ORM into an RCP application?
Thanks for taking the time to think about my question.
Timothy

Comment: If it hasn't been done as Eclipse plug-ins there won't be an update site.

Comment: @greg-449 - A less technical question ... what options are available in an RCP application for JPA.  I've been using EclipseLink but when moving from Java 1.8 to Java 14, there are many issues.

Comment: Sorry I don't know, not something I use

Comment: Thanks for your time!